# Tabular Caption?

Tags: tables

I have a table that I would like to put a caption below the table. I used the code `\caption{}`, but it shows an error. I have done the code as below. How can add the caption below?

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
            \hline
        Topic & 
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}
        {\centering $ Z_{1} $ }
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\centering $ Z_{2} $ }
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\centering $ Z_{3} $ }\\
        \hline

    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Document}  
    & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{$ \vartheta_{d,1} $}    
    & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ words}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{$ \vartheta_{d,2} $}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ words}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{$ \vartheta_{d,3} $}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ words}\\


    \hline
    \hline
    $ d_{1} $   & 0.6    & $  w_{1} $,$  w_{2} $,$  w_{3} $,$  w_{2} $,$  w_{1} $ 
    & 0.2 & $  w_{1} $, $  w_{9} $ , $  w_{8} $
    & 0.2 & $  w_{7} $,$  w_{10} $,$  w_{10} $\\
    $ d_{2} $   & 0.2   & $  w_{2} $,$  w_{4} $,$  w_{4} $ & 0.5 & $  w_{7} $,$  w_{8} $,$  w_{1} $,$  w_{8} $,$  w_{8} $
    & 0.3 & $  w_{1} $,$  w_{11} $,$  w_{12} $\\
    $ d_{3} $   & 0.3   & $  w_{2} $,$  w_{1} $,$  w_{7} $,$  w_{5} $ & 0.3 & $  w_{7} $,$  w_{3} $,$  w_{3} $,$  w_{2} $ & 0.4 & $  w_{4} $,$  w_{7} $,$  w_{10} $,$  w_{11} $\\
    $ d_{4} $   & 0.3   & $  w_{2} $,$  w_{7} $,$  w_{6} $ & 0.4 & $  w_{9} $,$  w_{8} $,$  w_{1} $ & 0.3 & $  w_{1} $,$  w_{11} $,$  w_{10} $\\

    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{This is my one big figure\label{fig:somefig}}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You need to encase the `tabular` material in a `table` environment.

Comment: If that does not work, a [full MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows the rest of your document setup would be really helpful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to provide a `table` environment that encases the `tabular` environment as well as the `\caption` and `\label` statements.

```
% \documentclass statement and preamble
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
    % body of tabular environment 
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{This is my one big table} \label{tab:sometab}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

P.S If you want to add the table inside your own .text file you don't need to use these:

```
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

for caption get the same problem and after checking others similar issues and solution i decide to use a sidewaystable and  I add a caption without any problem:

```
\begin{sidewaystable} 
    \centering
    \begingroup % make the next setting local
    \captionsetup{type=table} % here we want to caption a table
    \caption{your caption here }
    \label{tab:the table label}
    \begin{tabular}{lrlllllll}
    \toprule
    \midrule

    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
\end{sidewaystable}
```

don't forget tp put this lines on the preambule

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

Comment: sorry, how this answer OP question? why someone should use `figure` environment for table and than do all complication (which works!), as you propose? well, it is possible, we newer know ...

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please make sure that your answer fits the question. I think its not a good idea to use figure environment for tables. HAve a look tothe topic minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) for the future. Thanks

Comment: Not that the OP asked, but there's `sidewaystable` as an environment instead of `sidewaysfigure`, then you wouldn't have to go through the trouble to change the caption type.. My point being, there shouldn't ever arise a need to place a table in a figure environment

Comment: @Troy thanks !! thnik it shlould be sidewaystable instead let me edit the response

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi No, that's merely additional fluff. Greeshma's question doesn't necessitate a `sidewaystable`, so your answer (while it may work), is *not* relevant, sorry.